# Calculation of beams in flat roof structure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering

Beams 1 to 7 carry the load of the roof (for example 200N/m2)
The maximum bend of these beams is 5mm
How do I calculate the forces working on these beams?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Is there a beam at 1, 2, 5, 6 the same as 7?

Comment: Yes, I apologise for the bad drawing skills. (Haven't found a good drawing app on iOS)

Comment: Tangential: if you have a stylus Autodesk Sketchbook is great for making drawings

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to model it in a program like STAAD or Tekla.

What is most important is to understand your load - earthquake, wind, snow, self-load from the roof.
You also need to define where the columns are in the above diagram after you define that you can start to solve the problem.